# jQuery hide parent but not child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to hide the parent of a child element but not the child element itself.

```html
<div class="bordered">
    <div class="banner-outer">
        <span class="text">My text content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I do something like:

```js
$(".bordered").hide();
$(".text").show();
```

The inner most element `.text` remains hidden because of the parent. Is there a way to only show the child element?

Comment: if this is a style issue, just use css classes to switch/ remove/ add style

Comment: This is not possible. Maybe re-think the inner structure of the element.

Comment: not using jquery's `hide` (which just adds `display: none` to the element's styles). if you hide the parent element, the parent element will be hidden. since the parent element *contains* the child element, the child element will be hidden too. the child element is part of the parent element.

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit more? It sounds like a styling issue as mentioned above. I could give an example of how to achieve your goal if I knew the requirement. Logic dictates, hiding a parent element will hide anything it contains. You could clone the child and append it after the parent and then hide the parent, but this is convoluted and a better solution probably exists.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to hide something specific on the parent element? Maybe just the background?? There are other approaches for that...

Comment: It is true, this is more of a structuring issue. I believe Chris has hit the nail on the head with his answer. I originally wasn't sure if it was possible to override the parent element's display attribute on the child. Removing the parents works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, No.

But, you can do something like move the ".text" span to be a child of your ".bordered" div.

```
$span=$(".text").clone();
$(".text").remove();
$(".bordered").append($span);
```

I would also suggest using ID's rather than classes if you are going to be manipulating the DOM like this.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the work-around I was looking for. I wasn't sure if it was possible to do so this answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

**By definition, if you hide the parent div, the childs are also hidden.**

You have to proceed in a different way.

**But** if you just want to cancel the "bordered" class effect, you can remove the class like that:

```
$(".bordered").removeClass("bordered");
```

You could also do a copy of the child div and append it to the document.

Comment: How does removing the class solve the problem???

Comment: If it's just a styling question, it's a possible solution.

Comment: But if he removes the class, he won't hide the parent at all... That's not the point of the question...